# XSLT 2.0 matching expression

Tags: xml, xslt

The following is my xml

```
<GSP VER="3.2">
<TM>0.065909</TM>
<Q>Michael</Q>
<PARAM name="q" value="Michael" original_value="Michael"/>
<PARAM name="btnG" value="Google Search" original_value="Google+Search"/>
<PARAM name="access" value="a" original_value="a"/>
<PARAM name="output" value="xml_no_dtd" original_value="xml_no_dtd"/>
<PARAM name="sort" value="date:D:L:d1" original_value="date:D:L:d1"/>
<PARAM name="wc" value="200" original_value="200"/>
<PARAM name="site" value="default_collection" original_value="default_collection"/>
..
```

I want to match the the value of the attribute 'value' which is 'Michael'.

Here is my xslt.

```
 <xsl:template name="gsa_custom_tabs">
    <xsl:variable name="tabs">
      <tabs>
        <tab name="All" col="default_collection" ctype="All_tab"></tab>
        <tab name="Courses" col="file_system" ctype="file_system"></tab>
        <tab name="Policies" col="policy" ctype="policy"></tab>
        <tab name="Library" col="lib" ctype="lib"></tab>
        <tab name="Other Systems" col="other" ctype="other"></tab>
      </tabs>
    </xsl:variable>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//xxx/collection_tabs.css"></link>
  <div class="container" id="centeredmenu">
    <ul class="search-collection-list desktop"> 
        <xsl:for-each select="$tabs/tabs/tab">
          <xsl:variable name="col" select="@col" />
             <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="/GSP/PARAM[@name='site']/@value = 'default_collection'">
                  <li class="search-collection-tab-item" id="active">
                    <a href="{$gsa_search_root_path_prefix}?{$custom_tab_url}&amp;site={$col}" ctype="{@ctype}" class="Active">                 
                      <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <li class="search-collection-tab-item">
                <xsl:variable name="debug" select="/GSP/PARAM[@name='site']/@value"></xsl:variable>
                <a href="{$gsa_search_root_path_prefix}?{$custom_tab_url}&amp;site={$col}" ctype="{@ctype}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of> 
                  <xsl:value-of select="$debug"></xsl:value-of>
                </a>
              </li>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

assume that the value of variable $col is Michael.

The when test fails even though I can see the XML contains the node.

Comment: I am showing the entire code.

Answer (score 0):

A xsl test needs a condition and you use a selector.

You should use something like :

```
<xsl:when test="PARAM/@value = 'site'">
...
</xsl:when>
```

because in your case you just return the `PARAM` node found with the attributs values, but make no test on it :

```
/GSP/PARAM[(@name='site') and (@value='default_collection')]
```

I would do something like this :

```
<li class="search-collection-tab-item" id="active">
  <a href="{$gsa_search_root_path_prefix}?{$custom_tab_url}&amp;site={$col}" ctype="{@ctype}">
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
         <xsl:if test="/GSP/PARAM[@name='site']/@value = 'default_collection'">Active</xsl:if>
      </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"></xsl:value-of>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: that did not work. The tab needs to be active if the value of  PARAM with attribute name = 'site' has value = 'default_collection'

Comment: answer updated. But you still need to correct something because as I see your current node from the loop is `tab` and I don't see this in your xml snippet...

Comment: I created a variable called `<xsl:variable name="debug" select="/GSP/PARAM[@name='site']/@value"></xsl:variable>` and it does not have any value in it.